# Best Linear Predictor for $X_{t+1}$ in term of conditional MMSE

Tags: time-series, probability, mathematical-statistics

For a zero-mean stationary stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$, assume that $\hat{X}_{t+1}$ as a linear combination of $X_t, X_{t-1}, ..., X_1$ is the **best linear predictor** for $X_{t+1}$ in term of **unconditional** minimum mean squared error MMSE (i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X_{t+1} - f(\mathcal{F}_t))^2$ is minimized if $f(\mathcal{F}_t) = \hat{X}_{t+1}$).  $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set of all past observations.

Is $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$, still the best linear predictor for $X_{t+1}$ in term of **conditional** MMSE? (i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X_{t+1} - f(\mathcal{F}_t)|\mathcal{F}_t)^2$ is minimized if $f(\mathcal{F}_t) = \hat{X}_{t+1}$).  $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set of infinitely past observations. Of course, it is a random variable.

Comment: What is MMSE abbreviating?

Comment: Sorry. Minimum mean square error! @jcken